# get line item id of loaded AMP Ads

Tags: javascript, amp-html, double-click-advertising, google-publisher-tag, amp-ad

So, GPT provides a function in its API getResponseInformation() that can be used to get info about the loaded ad such as lineItemId, advertiserId, campaignId, creativeId, etc. This function when used in tandem with the SlotRenderEndedEvent is very useful. However, as far as I know, this is only available for non amp ads.

I'm trying to find a similar function for AMP ads. Does anyone know of any such feature that AMP offers with which I can get atleast the lineItemId of the loaded ad?

P.S.: I'm looking for solutions on client side, in Javascript.

references:

getResponseInformation()
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.slotrenderendedevent

SlotRenderEndedEvent
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.ResponseInformation